# How to show a Select list (dropdown) for state and dependent cities of India?

Tags: 7

I want to show the list of state and city of particular state in dropdown.

I have done it using the Conditional Fields module but not helpful as I have to show the filter for cities in view.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using cities and states as taxonomy values..?

Comment: No It will take too  much time.

Comment: As i have to show the list of Indian state and cities of each state

Answer (score 2):

If you have City and State list in CSV, you can import to taxonomy using **[Taxonomy CSV import/export](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv)** module.

> This module allows you to import or export taxonomy from or to a CSV
>   (comma-separated values) file or with a copy-and-paste text.

you can use [**Hierarchical Select**](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) Module to list it in content type

you can find Indian states and city list in xlsx format [here](http://code.google.com/p/mysql-dumps/downloads/detail?name=city.xlsx)

Answer (score 1):

I like to suggest [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) Module.

> Hierarchical Select has the ability to save the entire lineage of a selection or only the "deepest" selection. You can configure it to force the user to make a selection as deep as possible in the tree, or allow the user to select an item anywhere in the tree. Levels can be labeled, >you can configure limit the number of items that can be selected, configure a title for the dropbox, choose a site-wide animation delay, and so on. You can even create new items and levels through Hierarchical Select!